# merging two sorted arraylist into one sorted arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array1.size() && j < array2.size();) {
    if (array1.get(i) < array2.get(j)) {
        list.add(array1.get(i));
        i++;
    } else {
        list.add(array2.get(j));
        j++;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't get to the largest number. For example, if I have two arrays {1, 3, 5} and {2, 4, 6}, that code gives me {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code is almost correct, just think what happens when you use all the elements of one of the arrays.

Comment: i < array1.size() already results in false when last element in array2 still is there

Comment: what the expected result you want?

Comment: Conjunction junction... how's that function?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-join-arrays/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers using stream are correct, but I would like to provide the solution starting from your code for completeness.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < array1.size() && j < array2.size();) {
    if (array1.get(i) < array2.get(j)) {
        list.add(array1.get(i));
        i++;
    } else {
        list.add(array2.get(j));
        j++;
    }
}

while(i < array1.size()) list.add(array1.get(i++));
while(j < array2.size()) list.add(array2.get(j++));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop will exit if one of `i < array1.size()` or `j < array2.size()` conditions fails, meaning it won't process (and sort) remaining elements in the other array.

Here's the `stream` approach to concatenate and sort two arrays:

```
int[] a1 = new int[]{1,3,5};
int[] a2 = new int[]{2,4,6};
List<Integer> result = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a1), Arrays.stream(a2))
    .boxed()
    .sorted()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add Integer Max Value at the end of both of the list and change the `and` condition to `or` condition**

```
List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5));
List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6));

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

array1.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //Add Integer Max Value
array2.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE); //Add Integer Max Value

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array1.size() - 1 || j < array2.size() - 1; ) {
    if (array1.get(i) < array2.get(j)) {
        list.add(array1.get(i));
        i++;
    } else {
        list.add(array2.get(j));
        j++;
    }
}

System.out.println(list);

array1.remove(array1.size() - 1); //Remove Integer Max Value
array2.remove(array2.size() - 1); //Remove Integer Max Value
```

Answer (score 0):

In above your code your using condition i < array1.size() && j < array2.size() so if one list exhaust first then it will go out of loop and will not process the remaining element in the second list.So after the loop you need to process the list if the counter is not reached the end.

```
 int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < array1.size() && j < array2.size()) {
                if (array1.get(i) < array2.get(j)) {
                    list.add(array1.get(i));
                    i++;
                } else {
                    list.add(array2.get(j));
                    j++;
                }
            }
            while (i < array1.size()) {
                list.add(array1.get(i));
                i++;
            }
            while (j < array2.size()) {
                list.add(array2.get(j));
                j++;
            }
```